# aws_access_key_id in aws lambda environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm using boto3 in order to create a presigned post url for s3.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=f"{userid}.{suffix}"
    )
```

The `aws_access_key_id` that is being used is incorrect, one of the ways of using the right one is by adding an environment variable through environment variables.

Any idea how can I enforce using the aws access key as defined by the user I've created in IAM ?

### Update 1

Policy attached to the IAM role that executes the lambda

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:ResetNetworkInterfaceAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kinesis:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Update 2

**Role in IAM**
[image: Role in IAM]
**Role configuration in Lambda configuration**
[image: Role configuration in Lambda configuration]

Comment: The right way is to attach the correct IAM policy to Lambda's IAM role. Then you do not need to specify the credentials explicitly.

Comment: @helloV thank you. I've attached the policy, what am I missing ?

Comment: Role credentials have an access-key-id beginning with `ASIA` (not `AKIA`), and it rotates.  "The access key does not exist in our records" is the error thrown if the request lacks the accompanying `x-amz-security-token` that gives meaning to the temporary access-key-id.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot but from where can I get `x-amz-security-token` ? am I suppose to get it back as part of the response ?

Comment: It should automatically be in the environment as `aws_session_token`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot found it, added it as an header and read about http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html but I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 8):

You should not use an IAM User for any sort of execution permissions in lambda. Rather, use an IAM role with appropriate policies attached and [attach that role to your Lambda function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html#lambda-intro-execution-role).

Also note that once the role is configured, the access id and secret will be automatically set as environment variables by lambda and Boto will retrieve them without any additional configuration.

Comment: I've attached the policy, what am I missing ?

Comment: @efi-mk, looking at your update, the policy has sufficient privileges to S3, can you share any stack trace from the execution? Also, how is the lambda deployed? In a VPC? If so, public or private subnet?

Comment: I am getting the following error: 
_The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records._

The access key does not exist in my IAM users. I'm using zappa for deployment, it's not part of any VPC

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the access key and secret key or letting lambda populate them based on the attached role? Also, I'm seeing similar issues on [AWS Developer forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=197439) and [GitHub](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1971) where the root problem was not also setting a session token when using role-based credentials. I believe session token should be set automatically if lambda is setting the credentials. I've used "os.environ" in my python scripts frequently to see what all env variables are being set at runtime

Comment: From where the aws key arrives ? I don't have any key in the system that resembles that key. I have a single iam user

Comment: Your update says you have an IAM Role. Do you have an IAM Role (with the policy above) and is it set as the execution role for your lambda? Or do you only have the single IAM user?

Comment: see me new update, I added images that show the configuration

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Zappa (InvalidClientTokenId). How did you manage to solve it? I'm sure AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID is set in the request